# Android dismiss AlertDialog to getting error

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my application, when i dismiss alert dialog then getting error java.lang.IllegalStateException. I open dialog fragment from clicking on positive button. But everytime  it causes error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.icanstudioz.android.njoyful, PID: 18564
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3718)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3564)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3540)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:444)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:217)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:240)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:361)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:262)
        at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:399)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1813)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:989)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Code is here,

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Select").setView(np);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        currentItem.setItemQuantity(String
                                .valueOf(np.getValue()));
                        v.setSelected(true);
                        if (currentItem.getModifier_group()
                                .length() == 0) {
                            NjoyApplication
                                    .getInstance()
                                    .addNewItemWithModifiers(
                                            currentItem, "0", false);
                            updateCart();
                        } else {
                            DialogFragment dialogFrag = new selectModifier();
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putString("ID", currentItem.getId()
                                    + "");
                            dialogFrag.setArguments(b);
                            dialogFrag.setTargetFragment(
                                    Create_Order_ListFragment.this,
                                    Modifier.SELECT_NEW_MODIFIER);
                            b.putInt("REQUEST_CODE",
                                    Modifier.SELECT_NEW_MODIFIER);
                            dialogFrag.setCancelable(true);
                            dialogFrag.show(getFragmentManager(),
                                    "dialog");
                        }
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        v.setSelected(false);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();
```

see on createview(),

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.common_gridview, container,false);
}
```

Comment: what is dialog?? you have called dialog.dismiss(). i think it is AlertDialog am i right?

Comment: yaeh... its dialog interface object.

Comment: sorry... its very large code. but i open this alert dialog from clicking on listview.

Comment: What is .setView(np); ?

Comment: it is number picker.

Answer (score 1):

```
1. if you are using fragment than make sure,

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reject, container,false);
    return view;
    }
in above code there should be **false** after container.


2. you must set the content view for the activity only once. **setContentView(XYZ);**


########======#######
try this in oncreatview,
if (view != null) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    if (parent != null) {
        parent.removeView(view);
    }
}
try {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
} catch (InflateException e) {

}
```

Comment: try changing  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.common_gridview, null);

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare `dialog` locally.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

The problem is you are trying to attach same AlertDialog in an Activity twice, try create new one each time.

Try this code.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                final AlertDialog alertd = builder.create();
                builder.setTitle("Select").setView(np);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        currentItem.setItemQuantity(String
                                .valueOf(np.getValue()));
                        v.setSelected(true);
                        if (currentItem.getModifier_group()
                                .length() == 0) {
                            NjoyApplication
                                    .getInstance()
                                    .addNewItemWithModifiers(
                                            currentItem, "0", false);
                            updateCart();
                        } else {
                            DialogFragment dialogFrag = new selectModifier();
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putString("ID", currentItem.getId()
                                    + "");
                            dialogFrag.setArguments(b);
                            dialogFrag.setTargetFragment(
                                    Create_Order_ListFragment.this,
                                    Modifier.SELECT_NEW_MODIFIER);
                            b.putInt("REQUEST_CODE",
                                    Modifier.SELECT_NEW_MODIFIER);
                            dialogFrag.setCancelable(true);
                            dialogFrag.show(getFragmentManager(),
                                    "dialog");
                        }
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        v.setSelected(false);
                        alertd.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: actually error doesn't get from onNegativeButton part. When i clicked on positive button, then it was giving me error.

Comment: try to call alertd.dismiss(); in setPositiveButton()

Comment: same problem.. please something new things needed.